# CakePHP form appending div and label automatically

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I am using Cakephp 2.2.3 version. When I create form using Cake form helpers, it automatically appends a div and label to the input type field. How to avoid it?

Following is the code:

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array('id' => 'username', 'class' => 'login-inp', 'type' => 'text')); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use options array of input to avoid form appending div and label automatically. Set `div` and `label` of options array to `false`.

```
echo $this->Form->input('username',
         array('id' => 'username', 'class' => 'login-inp',
               'div' => false, 'label' => false
         )
     );
```

Answer (score 3):

That's what `FormHelper::input()` is supposed to do. If you don't want the label and wrapping div just use the functions to generate specific input elements only like `FormHelper::text()`, `FormHelper::select()`, `FormHelper::radio()`, etc.